# Angular 2 and Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typescript, angular, angular2-template

I try to use Bootstrap with Angular2 and I have a problem with a autobinding of Bootstrap features.

Example for collapse:

```
<i class="wrapper fa fa-play rotate-90 triangle_{{level.id}}" [hidden]="!level.child.length" data-toggle="collapse" href="#dropdownMenu_{{level.id}}" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="dropdownMenu_{{level.id}}"></i>
```

An error:

```
Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'href' since it isn't a known native property ("r fa fa-play rotate-90 triangle_{{level.id}}" [hidden]="!level.child.length" data-toggle="collapse" [ERROR ->]href="#dropdownMenu_{{level.id}}" aria-expanded="true"
                       aria-controls="dropdownMenu_{{level.id")
```

This error is showing for all custom attributes.
Is there way to fix it or I should use JS function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the problem is but

```
attr.href="#dropdownMenu_{{level.id}}"
```

should be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

try [href] instead of href.

```
<i class="wrapper fa fa-play rotate-90 triangle_{{level.id}}" [hidden]="!level.child.length" data-toggle="collapse" [href]="'#dropdownMenu_' + level.id" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="dropdownMenu_{{level.id}}"></i>
```